# htaccess / mod_rewrite showing 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a very simple htaccess file in place to rewrite the page URL's.

For example I have

```
RewriteRule ^frequently-asked-questions faq.php [L]
```

The problem I am having is that when I navigate to `domain.com/frequently-asked-questions` it shows me a 404 as follows:

```
The requested URL /domain.com/frequently-asked-questions was not found on this server.
```

Navigating to `domain.com/faq.php` works.

The point is, it seems to be adding the domain name in the 404 error and it isn't recognising that it has to be looking for `/faq.php` - although I'm guessing that if I can get rid of the former (the domain name from the 404) it will solve the latter part.

Full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^landowners landowners.php [L]
RewriteRule ^frequently-asked-questions faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^company company.php [L]
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes - it seems to be in play as I have added a couple of lines to try and force the document root / domain etc and it throws a 500 Internal Error.

Comment: Check with this way.Put index.php after the domain and check."domain.com/index.php/frequently-asked-questions"

Comment: Are you sure you want to Rewrite instead of Redirect?

Comment: Can you post your existing .htaccess in question?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Buddhi - that didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^frequently-asked-questions faq.php [L,R]` and see if redirect works?

Comment: Why is the requested URL `/domain.com/...`? Do you have any other rules? Looks from that message that the something is adding your domain as part of the path.

Comment: Yes, I know that - that is really my questions. Nothing else in the htaccess. This pushed it to the faq.php page: RewriteRule ^frequently-asked-questions faq.php [L,R] - but I have just changed my links to that anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you have this .htaccess in `DocumentRoot` folder?

Comment: Yes. The server details are provided, but when I do a php document root check - it is the root. Not to worry - it is what it is. Thanks to everybody for their help. V appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your htaccess file is in root folder and faq.php is also in root folder, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^frequently-asked-questions/$ faq.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: @David what did you get when using above code? Have you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes, tried a new browser, just the same result. 404 error with /domain.com/frequently-asked-questions cannot be found on this server.

Comment: @David in your original htacecss i see no rule for adding /domain.com to your urls. Is this htaccess the full one? The on you use on your site? Is there any rue on your server-side script that may add /domain.com to your urls/links?

Comment: The problem is that the server details have been provided. I didn't get this on my development server. I have asked them to investigate - but I'm not expecting any kind of meaningful response. Thanks for your help though. The htaccess is the full one.

Answer (score 0):

The company providing the server details found a solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```